# How do I implement sorting on a integer column?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

```
const customerList = [{"ID":1,"name":"Queen","email":"Queen@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":13,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":2,"name":"Jack","email":"Jack@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-30T02:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":3,"name":"Nolan","email":"Nolan@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":6,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":4,"name":"Janet","email":"Janet@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":7,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":5,"name":"Loris","email":"Loris@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":8,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":6,"name":"Bree","email":"Bree@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":3,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":7,"name":"Daphne","email":"Daphne@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-15T09:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":8,"name":"Bari","email":"Bari@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":4,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":9,"name":"Billy","email":"Billy@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":5,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":10,"name":"Belia","email":"Belia@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":11,"name":"Moses","email":"Moses@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":9,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":12,"name":"Alex","email":"Alex@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":7,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-02-10T01:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":13,"name":"Alix","email":"Alix@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":8,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":14,"name":"Wendell","email":"Wendell@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":15,"name":"Ceola","email":"Ceola@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":5,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"}]
```

```
  <th class="countheader" onClick={() => sortCountCustomer}>
    Counts of Visit {getCountArrow()}
  </th>
```

```
  const [counterCount, setcounterCount] = useState(0);

  function sortCountCustomer() {
    const sortedCountCustomer = [...customerList];
    let sortCountVisit = counterCount;
        
    //check the current sortCount, if it is 2 then go back to 1,
    //if not then increase by 1

    if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
      sortCountVisit = 1;
      setCounterCount(1);
    } else {
      sortCountVisit += 1;
      setCounterCount(sortCountVisit);
    }

    console.log(sortCountVisit);
    
    if (sortCountVisit < 3) {
      sortedCountCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
          return x.counts_of_visit < y.counts_of_visit ? 0 : x.counts_of_visit ? -1 : 1;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return x.counts_of_visit > y.counts_of_visit ? 0 : x.counts_of_visit ? 1 : -1;
        }
      });
      setCustomerList(sortedCountCustomer);
    }
  }
```

My function does not work when sorting the integer number from ascending and descending
although I called the function to sort onClick method when I click the header

I edited my code to show where customerList and countercount come from

Comment: What is ```customerList``` and ```counterCount```?

Comment: @ikhvjs hi I can't view suggested edits pls post an answer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is HTML code in JavaScript code. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jabaa noted java remove the html code from the jaasript

Comment: I can't remove it. There is a pending edit.

Comment: @jabaa could you then post an answer on how im going to sort this integer column?

Comment: No, I can't. I can't reproduce your problem. I suggest to remove React and Axios from this question. Add an example input and expected output. Create an interactive in your question.

Comment: @jabaa its ready for editing now

Comment: Now you can provide a [mcve] without React and Axios and with example input and expected output.

Comment: @jabaa how so???

Comment: Add actual values for `customerList`, `setCustomerList` and the other variables. You're asking for debugging help but you're not providing a code that can be debugged. Create a code that reproduces your problem and that doesn't require external data.

Comment: Regarding: `onClick={() => sortCountCustomer}` I think this should either be `onClick={() => sortCountCustomer()}` or `onClick={sortCountCustomer}`

Comment: @BenStephens yes that aside the sorting logic doesn't. work 
return x.counts_of_visit < y.counts_of_visit ? 0 : x.counts_of_visit ? -1 : 1;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return x.counts_of_visit > y.counts_of_visit ? 0 : x.counts_of_visit ? 1 : -1;
        }

Comment: It's probably bothering you that I repeat it again: please provide a [mcve]. You're current code snippet can't be debugged. You can either remove React or you could create an example with Stackblitz.

Comment: @jabaa https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ht5usz
sort this numbers

Comment: I don't understand the question. Sorting works in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```js
const base_customerList = [{"ID":1,"name":"Queen","email":"Queen@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":13,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":2,"name":"Jack","email":"Jack@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-30T02:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":3,"name":"Nolan","email":"Nolan@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":6,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":4,"name":"Janet","email":"Janet@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":7,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":5,"name":"Loris","email":"Loris@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":8,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":6,"name":"Bree","email":"Bree@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":3,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":7,"name":"Daphne","email":"Daphne@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-04-15T09:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":8,"name":"Bari","email":"Bari@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":4,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":9,"name":"Billy","email":"Billy@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":5,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":10,"name":"Belia","email":"Belia@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":11,"name":"Moses","email":"Moses@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":9,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":12,"name":"Alex","email":"Alex@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":7,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-02-10T01:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":13,"name":"Alix","email":"Alix@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":8,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"Yes"},{"ID":14,"name":"Wendell","email":"Wendell@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":2,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"},{"ID":15,"name":"Ceola","email":"Ceola@gmail.com","counts_of_visit":5,"latest_time_of_visit":"2021-03-12T12:08:23.000Z","contacted":"No"}];


const Table = () => {
  const [counterCount, setCounterCount] = React.useState(3);
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = React.useState(base_customerList);
  
  function sortCountCustomer() {
    const sortedCountCustomer = [...base_customerList];
    let sortCountVisit = counterCount;

    if (sortCountVisit === 3) {
      sortCountVisit = 1;
      setCounterCount(1);
    } else {
      sortCountVisit += 1;
      setCounterCount(sortCountVisit);
    }

    if (sortCountVisit < 3)
      sortedCountCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
          return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return y.counts_of_visit - x.counts_of_visit;
        }
      });
    
    setCustomerList(sortedCountCustomer);
  }
  
  return (<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th onClick={() => sortCountCustomer()}>
          Counts of Visit
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {customerList.map((c) => (
        <tr key={c.ID}>
          <td>{ c.name }</td>
          <td>{ c.counts_of_visit }</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>);
};

const App = () => <Table />;
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can explain this part
return (x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit) * (sortCountVisit === 2 ? 1 : -1); 

What do the numbers negative and positive mean

Comment: @max It allows the sort order to be reversed. `x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit` gives you a positive or negative integer (or zero); if sortCountVisit !== 2 then the sort order is reversed by multiplying that positive or negative integer by -1.

Comment: ```
sortedCountCustomer.sort(function (x, y) {
        if (sortCountVisit === 1) {
          return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? -1
            : 1;
        } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) {
          return y.counts_of_visit - x.counts_of_visit
            ? 0
            : x.counts_of_visit
            ? 1
            : -1;
        }
```

I would like to use this can?

Comment: @max To be honest I'm not 100% sure what that piece of code is supposed to be doing. Hmmm ... Maybe you could try `if (sortCountVisit === 1) { return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit; } else if (sortCountVisit === 2) { return y.counts_of_visit - x.counts_of_visit; }` (Possibly the other way around.)

Comment: How do I make it 3rd click return original unsorted list?

Comment: @max The latest version does do that (I think).

Comment: hi Ive tried it and it doesn't, even the preliminary sort doesn't work on running code snippet

Comment: @max to start with it comes out as "Queen 13 Jack 2 Nolan 6 etc." (i.e. unsorted) after one click it comes out as sorted ascending, after two it's sorted descending and after another click it's back to "Queen 13 Jack 2 Nolan 6 etc.". How is that not what you're asking for?

Comment: when I run it and click on the header, nothing happens

Comment: @max it looks like it wasn't working in Chrome for some reason (but was working in Firefox). The current version appears to work in Chrome (for me anyway).

Comment: Can you explain why return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit; works and the reverse works? like why you take x - y and y -x for the other case?

Comment: could you explain 
xplain why return x.counts_of_visit - y.counts_of_visit; works and the reverse works? like why you take x - y and y -x for the other case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233530/discussion-between-max-and-ben-stephens).

Comment: @max Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007304/14454939 ?

Comment: doesn't help how do I undelete function in react?